# Usb Accessory stays connected after usb unplugged

Tags: android, usb, android-5.1.1-lollipop, accessory

I have an app that connects to a usb accessory. Simple, but the accessory stays connected even after the usb cable was unplugged.

This is my code:

```
public boolean checkOpenAccessory(){
        UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager)     getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
    UsbAccessory[] accessories = usbManager.getAccessoryList();
    UsbAccessory accessory;
    if(accessories == null ){
        accessory = null;
        return false;
    } else {
        accessory = accessories[0];
        if(usbManager.hasPermission(accessory)) {
            return (usbManager.openAccessory(accessory) != null);
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This returns me that I am connected to a usb accessory, but I am not. I have a developer app that monitors everything in the phone and says the same thing:

```
UsbAccessory[] accessories = usbManager.getAccessoryList();
```

Accessory is connected. I also tried something like triggering a broadcast or kill background processes. The phone it will show no accessories only if I restart it.

```
sendBroadcast(new Intent(UsbManager.ACTION_USB_ACCESSORY_DETACHED));
```

My problem is only a Htc One M9, Api 22, Android version 5.1 .
If you guys can help it would be a great thing, I spent a few days trying to figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some improvements.It works something like this.. but not 100 % sure.

```
boolean check = checkOpenAccessory();
```

And then use `checkOpenAccessory()` when is needed somewhere and will return the real thing.

Basically the second time will work, not 100% sure but it work.

[Refer to this link.](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=215688&q=accessory&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars)